# Error in making of Swipe Tabs in Android Studio

Tags: android, tabs, swipe

```
// I was making swipe Tabs in android Studio i got a error 
// i cannot paste all the code please follow this link to see more information
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVahIc8yENk
```

i also mention where i got a error and what error is please read this

```
package com.example.rahul.swipetabs;    

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.app.ActionBar;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    ActionBar mActionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mActionBar = getActionBar();         

        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
      //error #1
        mActionBar.Tab tab1 = mActionBar.newTab(); 
       //error #2 
        // i had explain all the errors below            
    }
}
```

mActionBar.<strike>setNavigationMode</strike>
    (ActionBar.<strike>NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS</strike>);

```
//error #1 : Here set Navigation mode & NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS  is depreciated 
// How can i solve this problem if it is depreciated 
//can i still use this if it is depreciated    

//mActionBar.Tab tab1 = mActionBar.newTab();  

//error #2 :  "Tab"  in code  says that Tab cannot resolve symbol
```

Comment: "can i still use this if it is depreciated" -- for a while, yes. Ideally, you use something else. There are many ways to create swipe tabs in Android: `TabLayout`, `PagerTabStrip`, third-party tab indicator libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use deprecated methods.

Instead of this :

```
      mActionBar.Tab tab1 = mActionBar.newTab();
```

Add this

```
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = mActionBar.newTab(); 
     tab1.setText("Tab 1");
```

**In in this, we need to call with ActionBar.Tab means Tab is a static field of ActionBar class thus we need to call this with class name instead of object name.**

Comment: can you explain me what does the code means and why does we use .Tab

Comment: @Aliaketh In in this, we need to call with ActionBar.Tab means Tab is a static field of ActionBar class.